# Save ArrayList for use on next program execution

Tags: c#, arraylist, save, settings.settings

I have a c# program that is saving data a user enters to a hidden xml file.  I want to be able to store the file name of the particular xml file so that when the user exits the progrma and re-enters it again they can select the name of that file from a drop-down list and load the data stored into that xml file into another form.  I was thinking about saving the name of the file to an array list since they are dynamic but am having trouble finding a way to save or hold onto the values in this array list so that they can be assigned to a comboBox on a form whenever the user enters the application.  Does anyone have any suggestions or ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are saving the XML file to disk, why not just read the directory for a list of files on the start of your application and then populate a drop-down with the file names you retrieved?

Answer (score 1):

1. Add `.settings` file to your project.
2. In settings editor provide name for your list of hidden files (e.g. HiddenFiles)
3. Select `StringCollection` type
4. Select scope (by default it is User)
5. Provide values in value editor.

Now your settings will be available from code this way:

```
combobox.DataSource = Settings.Default.HiddenFiles;
```

If you want to add another file name to this list (which will be available after this user starts application later):

```
if (Settings.Default.HiddenFiles == null)
    Settings.Default.HiddenFiles = new StringCollection();
Settings.Default.HiddenFiles.Add(pathToFile);
Settings.Default.Save();
```

Comment: It does not allow me to select a StringCollection type for the setting.  Sorry I am completely new and raw to these settings.  What do you mean by add a .settings file?  I am doing this in the Settings.settings directory under the Properties drop-down on the solution explorer.

Comment: No-no. Right-click on project name. Select `Add > New Item`. Under `General` node select `Settings File`. StringCollection will be available then.

Comment: Thank you and yes I did that howver I am getting an error when I perform the action that causes the path to the file to be adden to the HiddenFiles setting.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that is producing an exception during run-time.

Settings1.Default.eventSaveArrayList.Add(clubNameTextBox.Text.ToString() + " " + DateString);
            Settings1.Default.Save();

Comment: What kind of exception do you get? BTW you don't need to call .ToString() on properties of string type.

Comment: object reference not set to an instance of an object.   It says it is the following line of code :  Settings1.Default.eventSaveArrayList.Add(clubNameTextBox.Text + " " + DateString);

Comment: If you haven't provided default file names through editor, then you should create collection. See my updated answer.

Comment: awesome it now works! now I need to find a way to have it check to see if there are default file names through editor so it doesnt create a new array collection each time. I only need it to create a new array collection the very first time a user will be using this program.  I was able to figure this out myself so no need for additional help.  thanks again